# SQLite Connections-Results in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, caliburn.micro, .net-framework-version

I am having a weird problem in SQLite, here is the steps I did:

**Git Repo:** *https://github.com/moon1234moon/SQLiteApp*

### STEPS:

1. I created table Users in SQLite and added it to the front-end project in solution
2. I then included it in the project and set its properties to:

```
{
  "Build Action" => "Content",
  "Copy to Output Directory" => "Copy if newer"
}
```

3. Using this c# code I inserted data into Users table using the two functions in different classes:

**First function:**

```
public void Register(UserModel user, string password, bool autoLogin = true)
{
  string hashedPassword = Hasher.HashPassword(password);

  bool res = AuthDataAccess.SaveNewData("Users", ToListOfKeyValuePairs(user, hashedPassword));

  if (res == true && autoLogin == true)
  {
    Login(user.Username, password);
  }
}
```

**Second Function:**

```
public static dynamic SaveNewData(string tablename, List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> data)
{
  try
  {
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
      string query = queryBuilder.GetSaveDataQuery(tablename, data);

      cnn.Execute(query);

      return true;
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    return false;
   }
}
```

**This should execute this query:**

```
INSERT INTO Users(FirstName,LastName,Username,Password,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate) VALUES('Admin','Admin','admin','P2Y+8tZPRGwjcV8tQRDl9m1G2omLW248s5RK81iGnqdMXPh0','1/28/2020 12:45:07 PM','1/28/2020 12:45:07 PM');
```

4. After that I tried to execute the following query from c#:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = 'admin'
```

**Using this function:**

```
public static bool CheckIfUsernameExist(string username)
{
   try
   {
      using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString()))
      {
        string query = queryBuilder.GetByUsername(username);

        var user = cnn.Query<UserModel>(query, new DynamicParameters()).ToList();

        if(user.Count > 0)
        {
          return true;
        }

        return false;
     }
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

### HERE IS THE PROBLEM

**But the result contradicted on what I get from DB Broweser for SQLite:**

- In the DB Browser I got an empty Users table
- In C# I got:
  **users variable:**

```
    {
     user:  
     {
       Count: 1 System.Collections.Generic.List<DataAccess.Authentication.Models.UserModel>,
       [0]: DataAccess.Authentication.Models.UserModel} DataAccess.Authentication.Models.UserModel
       {
          CreatedDate   {1/28/2020 12:05:56 PM} System.DateTime
          FirstName "Admin" string
          Id    1   int
          LastName  "Admin" string
          Password  "32EgQocI8Oinbm3k4ZszPNXiHDE8ZpA+FJemCoevr8dTkKVT"  string
          UpdatedDate   {1/28/2020 12:05:56 PM} System.DateTime
          Username  "admin" string
       }
     }
    }
```

### WHY IS IT DIFFERENT??? ...

### After some testing turns out:

- C# is saving the data in `/bin/debug` directory
- While the DB Browser is getting from the project directory

### Problem is they are not synchronized .. How can we fix that???

Comment: Please help!! I added the whole repository if someone needs to check

Comment: you are right; see the properties of your database files; `copy to output Directory ` ;if it is `copy if newer` then your changes will be overwritten every time you change the data and build your project.  the solution: during the development, set the path hard coded and prevent the files to be copied .[Image](https://images.app.goo.gl/A7PTWCRPDuoakLW67)

Comment: One big problem is hiding exceptions with `catch{return false;}` This way you have no idea what went wrong. Exceptions are blown fuses. You don't ignore them

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what I have written, **because** what is really happening is Microsoft Visual studio is writing data to the debug database that is in `/bin/debug` directory **not in** the database that is in project.

Also, taking into consideration the properties that I set to the Db that is in the project's directory

```
{
    "Build Action" => "Content", 
    "Copy to Output Directory" => "Copy if newer"
}
```

this database gets **re-deployed** every time it is **not there** or every time it **gets changed**. So this is a blank database (the one in project's directory) it is overwriting the used database if it gets changed or if it not there it fills it again.

So this is the normal way to handle SQLite database, nothing was wrong with my code.

Comment: No, *your application* is writing records *to the database you told it to use* by specifying its path. When you use a relative path, it's relative to the working folder. The default working directory is the directory of the application's executable. That's `bin/debug` while debugging - that's where the executable is. That's what will be packed and deployed.

Comment: The INSERT statement has more serious problems too, like storing localized strings as dates. SQLite only recognizes [the ISO8601 string literal as a date](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .. Considering to your first comment, in my answer I was explaining why it is saving the database in the folder where the executable in.

Comment: That's not what happens. It's not Visual Studio that did anything. The connection string (which wasn't posted) contains a relative path. The working folder for any application is the folder it starts on, unless a different one is specified when launching it. VS doesn't specify a different working folder, so the application's location is the working folder.

Comment: You'll have to take that into account when deploying your application too. If you try to access content files (settings, images etc) from the *project* folder with `../..`, in deployment the code will try to load them from the wrong folder.

Comment: Another thing to consider, is that you simply can't modify files in `Program Files`. One reason is to prevent applications from overwriting one another due to bad paths. Older Windows versions would simply throw an Access Denied, but lazy programmers tried to make their files writable during deployment. Later versions will redirect those writes to other folders. There are specicif, well-known locations to store per-user or per-application documents and data. For app data, it's the %APPDATA% folder. That's where your database should be deployed

Comment: You can get the location for those special folders with the [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8) method, eg `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returns the roaming application data folder. `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` returns the non-roaming location